# make object variable

Tags: c#, object

I'm making a 7-segment clock in C# and I've come across a problem. I usually code in PHP and this problem is confusing to me.

Let's say I'm trying to assign locations to panels in C#
So first  use this code:

```
Panel a = new Panel();
Panel b = new Panel();
Panel c = new Panel();
Panel d = new Panel();
Panel e = new Panel();
Panel f = new Panel();
Panel g = new Panel();
```

I have an array:

```
int[,] locationArray = new int[,] {
    {10,20},
    {90,30},
    {90,125},
    {10,210},
    {5,125},
    {5,30},
    {10,115}
};
```

Than I loop through that array:

```
for (int d = 0; d < locationArray.GetLength(0); d++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < locationArray.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        int locationY = locationArray[i, j];
        int locationX = locationArray[i, 0];

        /* a has to be variable so that I could use one of the panels from a to g. */
        a.Location = new Point(locationX, locationY);
    }
}
```

So is it possible to make a.Location a variable from a to g without making it complicated/messy like a switch case or if statement.

I wanted to just iterate through an array above the first array to choose the letter. But it doesn't seem to work that way.

Comment: You could put them in an array: `var panels = new[] { a, b, c, ... };`. Then do `panels[i].Location = new Point...`. You also may not need to assign variables to them, so you could just do `var panels = new[] { new Panel(), new Panel(), ..., new Panel() };`

Comment: Or maybe simpler... `var panels = Enumerable.Range(1,7).Select(e => new Panel()).ToList();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add each panel to an array:

```
Panel[] panels = new [] { a, b, c, d, e, f, g };
```

Therefore, you can access a panel by its index inside your loops:

```
panels[d].Location = new Point(locationX, locationY);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having separate variables `a,b,c,d,e,f,g`, try maintaining an array or dictionary of panels, and then everything becomes much simpler:

```
var panels = new Panel[] { ... }
```

or

```
var panel = new Dictionary<int, Panel> { ... }
```

or

```
var panel = new Dictionary<string, Panel> { ... }
```

Another tip that will make your code more readable: replace the two-dimensional array `int[,]` with an array of location objects:

```
var locations = new Location[] { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But how do I add values to them? 
With the array it is: { {} , {} } how would I do it for the Location?

Comment: `var locations = new [] { new Location(10,20), new Location(90,30) };`
and you just need to add a constructor to the `Location` class that accepts two arguments and assigns them to fields. Take a look at the `Point` class which is part of the framework, it might suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list:

```
Panel a = new Panel();
Panel b = new Panel();
Panel c = new Panel();
Panel d = new Panel();
Panel e = new Panel();
Panel f = new Panel();
Panel g = new Panel();


List<Panel> listOfPanels = new List<Panel>(){a, b, c, d, e, f, g};

foreach (Panel panel in listOfPanels)
{
    // Your stuff goes here
}
```